# Why transition does not work in my Vue components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-transitions, vue-slot

I am building a Vue app. I have two components that are related to each other. One of them is called `loginRegister.vue` and the code of that is here:

> loginRegister.vue:

```html
<template>
<BaseModal idBtn = "regis" btnOneText="Cancel" :btnTwoText="button2Text['register']" v-show="showModal1" @close="showModal1 = false" @submitForm="registerUser(regLogPara['register'])" :popoverVue = "showToolTip.register">
            <!-- the material that must be shown in modal comes here. it is better to use bootstrap "card" classes for compatible design -->
            <!-- ################ -->
            <!-- transition part -->
            <!-- ################ -->
  <transition name="fade">
    <div v-if="modalAlert==='form'" key="item1">
      <h4 class="card-title text-center my-3">Create Your Account</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- showing success message -->
    <div v-else-if="modalAlert==='success'" key="item2">
      <p>you succeed</p>
    </div>
    <!-- showing error message -->
    <div v-else key="item3">
      <p>there is an error!</p>
    </div>
  </transition>
</BaseModal>
</template>

<script>
import BaseButton from './BaseButton.vue';
import BaseInput from './BaseInput.vue'
import BaseModal from './BaseModal.vue';
import { onMounted, reactive, ref } from 'vue';


export default {
  name: "loginRegister",
  components: {
    BaseModal,
    BaseButton,
    BaseInput
  },

  setup(props) {
    const showModal = ref(false);
    const showModal1 = ref(false);
    const modalAlert = ref("form");
    
    const registerUser = async (checkPara) => {
      /* This function is responsible for sending form data to backend and getting the result from backend */
      if (checkPara == "reset") {
        /* for showing form again if there is a back-end error */
        console.log("reset form");
        modalAlert.value = "form";
        button2Text["login"] = "Submit";
        button2Text["register"] = "Submit";
        regLogPara["login"] = "login";
        regLogPara["register"] = "register";
      } else {
        /* for submiting form */
        modalAlert.value = "error";
        button2Text[checkPara] = "Try again";
        regLogPara[checkPara] = "reset";
        console.log("register function");
      }
    }
    
  return {
      registerUser,
      showModal,
      showModal1,
      validation,
      blurInput,
      loginValid,
      registerValid,
      finalCheck,
      showToolTip,
      store,
      modalAlert,
      button2Text,
      regLogPara
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The other one called `BaseModal.vue` and the code of that is here:

> BaseModal.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div class="modal-overlay container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center" @click.self="$emit('close')">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <!-- text and other html comes here in the slot -->
            <!-- ############## -->
            <!-- this is the slot part -->
            <!-- ############## -->
            <slot></slot>
            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center">
              <base-button 
              large
              v-if="btnOneText"
              kind = "btn-secondary"
              :textBtn = "btnOneText" 
              @click="$emit('close')"
              >
              </base-button>

              <base-button 
              large
              v-if="btnTwoText"
              kind = "btn-secondary"
              :textBtn = "btnTwoText" 
              @click="popoverFunc"
              @blur="popoverDisable"
              :id="idBtn"
              >
              </base-button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BaseButton from './BaseButton.vue';
import bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";

export default {
  // $emit('submitForm'),
  name: "BaseModal",
  props: {
    btnOneText: {
      type: String
    },
    btnTwoText: {
      type: String
    },
    popoverVue: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    idBtn: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  computed: {
    popOverData: function () {
      return this.popoverVue;
    },
    popVar: function() {
      return new bootstrap.Popover(document.getElementById(this.idBtn), {
            trigger: "manual",
            title: "Notice:",
            content: "Please fill all fields in the correct way to submit your information!",
            customClass: "myPopover",
            placement: "top"
          })
    }
  },
  data() {
      return {
          showPopOver: false
      }
  },
  emits: ["close", "submitForm"],
  components: {
    BaseButton
  },
  watch: {
    popOverData: function (newState, oldState) {
      if(newState === true) {
        this.showPopOver = true;
        this.popoverFinal();
      } else {
        this.showPopOver = false;
        this.popoverFinal();
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    popoverFunc: function() {
      this.$emit('submitForm');
      if (this.popOverData) {
        this.showPopOver = true;
        this.popoverFinal();
      }
    },
    popoverDisable: function() {
      console.log("popoverDisable");
      this.showPopOver = false;
      this.popoverFinal();
    },
    popoverFinal: function() {
      console.log(this.showPopOver);
      /* this function is responsible for showing and hiding the popover according to "showPopOver" data */
      if (this.showPopOver) {
        this.popVar.show();
      } else {
        this.popVar.hide();
      }
    }
  }
  
};
</script>

<style scoped src="../assets/css/compoStyles/baseModal.css"></style>
```

There are some codes that are not related to this question and also I tried to simplify the codes and clarify the parts that are related to `transition` and `slot` in my components code.

Although the codes may seem long or complicated, the goal that I want to reach is simple. I want to submit a register form in a modal component. Actually the user in my app clicks on register button and then the `BaseModal.vue` component is shown. In that case the register form (that for simplicity I substitute that with a `h4` tag) is the default thing that user could see. After submitting the form according that the process is successful or there is an error, I want to show a message to the user and change the text of button from **submit** to **try again** if there is an error. After that when the user clicks `try again` button the form (`h4` tag) must be fade in again. So I tried the `v-if/v-else-if/v-else` structure of Vue in my `loginRegister.vue` component. The code that I used in `transition part` is similar to the code that [Vue documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-enterleave.html#transitioning-between-elements) is used, But the transition does not work correctly. In my local development environment, the `h4` tag disappears smoothly and then no message is shown, after clicking `try again` the `h4` tag fade in again. Also in the console I could see this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: <transition> can only be used on a single element or component. Use <transition-group> for lists. 
  at <BaseTransition mode=undefined appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="fade" > 
  at <BaseModal idBtn="regis" btnOneText="Cancel" btnTwoText="Try again"  ... > 
  at <LoginRegister> 
  at <App>
```

But I don't think that is related to my issue, because I did not use transition on multi elements in my app. So could anyone please help me that what is wrong in my codes?

Comment: could you try wrapping every conditional element with <transition> instead of if, else-if, and else thing? <transition> only supports 1 root element.

Comment: @Kunukn in the link that I put in my question Vue itself used 3 ```buttons``` in a single transition!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want baseModal.vue to be inside loginRegister.vue and the baseModal to have some kind of transition whenever some state changes? Try changing `<transition></transition>` into `<transition-group></transition-group>`